# select failed in php script with mysql_query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

below is my code .I guess there is something wrong with the code in `second line`,but I can not figure it out
**PS:The db has been connected successfully !**

Please help me to figure the problem out.Thanks a lot .

```
<?php
$today =date('Y-m-d');
$pr_result = mysql_query("SELECT mgr_open,mgr_project FROM mgr_admin WHERE mgr_start<= $today AND mgr_end >= $today")or die(mysql_error());
$pre=mysql_fetch_array($pr_result);

 
?>
```

Comment: `Do not use mysql_* functions. This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.`

Comment: Can you change your code to this and show us the error you are getting?

    $today =date('Y-m-d');
    $pr_result = mysql_query("SELECT mgr_open,mgr_project FROM mgr_admin WHERE mgr_start<= $today AND mgr_end >= $today") or die(mysql_error());
    $pre=mysql_fetch_array($pr_result);

Comment: @NLZ It didn't print any error information .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pr_result = mysql_query("SELECT mgr_open,mgr_project FROM mgr_admin WHERE mgr_start<= '$today' AND mgr_end >='$today'");
```

Comment: $today isn't a String ,it's a reference variable.So  why we should put '' here??

Comment: @andyqee `$today` contains `string` data, that's why we have to use single quote around it.